# Create Table DDL causes sql server to hang

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl

Is there anything in this DDL statement that could cause the system to hang and create long running query?

```
  -- Abort on any error
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
-- FUll isolation
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
CREATE TABLE ClientPayerCrosswalkMapping
( 
  id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
  lbxid INT NOT NULL,
  ClientPayerID NVARCHAR(80),

  CONSTRAINT PK_ClientPayerCrosswalkMapping_ID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id),
  CONSTRAINT UN_lbxid UNIQUE(lbxid),

  CONSTRAINT FK_LockboxDocumentTracking FOREIGN KEY (lbxid)
  REFERENCES LockboxDocumentTracking(lbxid)
);

GO
```

This is on SQL Server 2005, at that time system was under moderate load.

This is new table so why would the system hang, my only suspicion is that the table have a  **CONSTRAINT**

Comment: Do you really need a transaction and `SERIALIABLE` isolation level here? If its just one table being created, you can always just drop it again, e.g. if subsequent data population scripts fail.

Comment: Actually, Why do you need a transaction at all?

Comment: There supposed to be some records inserted into that table after it have been populated, that why we have a transaction. But yes it could have been executed without transaction

Comment: There can be problems with wrapping DDL statements with Transactions (except for #temporary tables which have special handling).  Try and move the `CREATE TABLE ..` outside of the transaction.

Comment: Also, anytime you are using `SERIALIZABLE`, you should expect possibly long delays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this without creating any transaction:

```
CREATE TABLE ClientPayerCrosswalkMapping
( 
  id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
  lbxid INT NOT NULL,
  ClientPayerID NVARCHAR(80),

  CONSTRAINT PK_ClientPayerCrosswalkMapping_ID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id),
  CONSTRAINT UN_lbxid UNIQUE(lbxid),

  CONSTRAINT FK_LockboxDocumentTracking FOREIGN KEY (lbxid)
  REFERENCES LockboxDocumentTracking(lbxid)
);
```